# Javascript Dom Products Listing

Tags: javascript

there is a simple order page on my website that I have prepared to improve myself.

When the order page is opened ,the" 1 piece " option is selected.

Do this ***" document.getElementById ('mark1').click () "*** I did it thanks to this code. But when you click on 1pc, you will see that it comes in their products.

My request is that 1 option is selected when the site is opened and the products are listed. How can I do this?

Page: https://fcproje.com/nike/siparis.php

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a [mcve] that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clicking that `<input type='radio'>` seems to trigger the following code on line 598 of your file

```js
$("#mark1").on('click', function() {
    var markalar = this.dataset.id;
    var mainid=1;
    if(markalar){
        for (var i =1; i <= mainid; i++) {
            sender(i,markalar);
        }
    }
});
```

You could simulate this code after the code you use to click on the radio button.

So change this line

```
 document.getElementById('mark1').click()
```

To this block of code;

```
document.getElementById('mark1').click();
(function(){
var markalar = "1"; // The Dataset.id of the input was "1" so add it here
var mainid=1;
if(markalar){
    for (var i =1; i <= mainid; i++) {
        sender(i,markalar);
    }
}
})();
```

The code is wrapped in an anonymous function as to not add unnecessary variables to the global window object.

Comment: Thank you, I've been trying for hours.

Comment: Beware though, other parts of your JavaScript seem to be throwing errors ( according to the browser's log console ), so whatever changes you make might not take affect until you fix the current errors. Current error; `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).mask is not a function on line 561 of siparis.php`.